# ASM COMPUTE_FRAMES Error with If + Assignment

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I once again have a problem with ASM and it's `COMPUTE_FRAMES`. Whenever I compile this code with my custom compiler (Bytecode below):

***Code***:

```
Random random = Random()
int i = 10
Object i1 = i

if (i == 10) i1 = "a";

println "test"
```

***Bytecode***:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=0, locals=0, args_size=1
     0: invokestatic  #14                 // InterfaceMethod dyvil/lang/Random.apply:()Ldyvil/lang/Random;
     3: astore_1      
     4: bipush        10
     6: istore_2      
     7: iload_2       
     8: invokestatic  #19                 // Method dyvil/lang/Int.apply:(I)Ldyvil/lang/Int;
    11: astore_3      
    12: iload_2       
    13: bipush        10
    15: if_icmpne     21
    18: ldc           #21                 // String a
    20: astore_3      
    21: ldc           #23                 // String test
    23: invokestatic  #29                 // Method dyvil/lang/Predef.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    26: return        
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        0      26     3    i1   Ljava/lang/Object;
        0      26     1 random   Ldyvil/lang/Random;
        0      26     2     i   I
        0      26     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
MethodParameters:
  Name                           Flags
  args
```

ASM causes this error upon `visitMaxs(0, 0)`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.objectweb.asm.Item.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.c(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
```

Unfortunately, since the creators of ASM insisted on obfuscating it (-.-), I am unable to figure out what the exact problem is here. I have tried removing the `if` statement (leaving the assignment) and replacing the assignment with a simple method call, but both alternatives did not cause any errors and worked perfectly. It is only the combination of `if` + assignment that seems to be causing this error.

Comment: ASM obfuscated? I just downloaded the source yesterday, so perhaps that's the way to go then..

Comment: I also have the source linked, but since the Stack Trace uses the binaries, it is obfuscated.

Comment: Just import the asm source into your source folder (or a separate project perhaps) and remove the binary dependency.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem using the code at http://pastebin.com/BkcczR1u together with ASM 5.0.3 and no exception was thrown. Does my code reproduce the error in your environment? Do you see any differencies?

Comment: I don't want to have the ASM source code in my projects for various reasons, and the obfuscation is so much of a problem. Your example works because all types are already determined, which is not the case for my compiler. I believe the problem lies in my implementation of the getCommonSuperClass method of ClassWriter, which returns `null` in some cases. One of these cases might be present in this situation, and ASM crashes because it (obviously) can't handle `null` in the `Item` constructor (which is used to reference Classes in the Constant Table).

Comment: Turns out getCommonSuperClass returning `null` actually *was* the problem. But now I face the problem of returning the proper type in situations like this, which probably involves getting rid of `COMPUTE_FRAMES` completely. But that's another story, thanks for the help, ... self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that my overridden `getCommonSuperClass` method in my `ClassWriter` implementation returned `null` in situations like this. Since ASM seems to supply the return value of that method to some `Item` constructor / method, the latter class (understandably) struggles with the value and simply crashes.

Checking the return value of `getCommonSuperClass` and returning `java/lang/Object` when it was `null` fixed the problem for me.

*(Just answering this so I can close the question and people who *might* face a similar problem know that they need to **check their `getCommonSuperClass`**)*